# why am I not able to pass token correctly in my Django views?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have below code

```
class ProxyAPI(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DummySerializer

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.org = None
        self.ent = None
        self.linkde = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        org = request.data.get("org")
        ent = request.data.get("ent")
        erpid = request.data.get("erpid")


        self.org = org
        self.ent = ent
        self.erpid = erpid

        combined_response = []
        post_api_views = [
            abc,
            xyz
        ]

        linkdetl = self.get_queryset()
        if not linkdetl:
            return Response("Link token not found.", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        token = linkdetl[0]

        for index, api_view_class in enumerate(post_api_views, start=1):
            try:
                api_instance = api_view_class(token)
                response = api_instance.post(request)

                if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
                    return Response("success")

            except Exception as e:
                error_message = f"Anddd error occurred while calling API {index}: {str(e)}"
                return Response({'error': error_message}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

        return Response(combined_response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class Info(APIView):
    token = None
    # def __init__(self):
    #     self.token = token
    #     super().__init__()

    # @staticmethod
    def get_info(self):
        comp_client = create_client(self.token)
        print(comp_client)
        try:
            organization_data = comp_client.accounting.company_info.list(expand=something)
            return organization_data
        except Exception as e:
            api_log(
                msg=f"Error retrieving organizations details: {str(e)} \
                 - Status Code: {status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR}: {traceback.format_exc()}")


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        organization_data = self.get_info()
        formatted_data = self.build_response_payload(organization_data)
        return Response(formatted_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        
        
class abc(APIView):
    token = None
    # def __init__(self):
    #     self.token = token
    #     super().__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        authorization_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if authorization_header and authorization_header.startswith('Bearer '):
            token = authorization_header.split(' ')[1]

            token = abc.token
            comp_list = Info(token=token)
            print(comp_list)
            response = comp_list.get(request)
            try:
                if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
                    merge_payload = response.data
                    lurl = 'https://example.com
                    data_insert = requests.post(lurl, json=merge_payload, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'})

                    if data_insert.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
                        return Response(f"successfully inserted")
                    else:
                        return Response({'error': 'Failed to send data'})

            except Exception as e:
                error_message = f"Failed to send data Error: {str(e)}"
                return Response({'error': error_message}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

            return Response({'error': 'Failed to retrieve information'}, status=response.status_code)
```

`ProxyAPI` API is calling multiple POST api internally inside `post_api_views` list. The API is also suppose to fetch some token from DB and pass it to those POST methods.

- To fetch token from DB ProxyAPI is calling a method called
  get_queryset().

  - The data is getting fetched properly.
  - abc is one of those multiple methods as shown above.
  - abc is calling get() from Info class
  - get() is calling get_info(), which is the data source, and even if the proxyAPI is passing the token to abc class's POST method, the
    token is supposed to be passed to create_client() in get_info()
    method.
  - But when I am trying to pass the token to those methods in the post_api_views list, I am getting below error

  {"error":"Anddd error occurred while calling API 1: View.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"}

Please suggest why am I getting the error. I haev already scratched all my hairs in last 10 hours without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the `init()` method of the `View` class is expecting only one positional argument, but two are being passed.

you could modify the `init()` method to accept two positional arguments:

```
def __init__(self, data, token, *args, **kwargs):

    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.org = None

    self.ent = None

    self.linkde = None

    self.data = data

    self.token = token
```

Otherwise you can modify the code to pass only one argument to the `init()` method.

```
View.init(self, request.data)
```

Or pass it as a keyword argument

`View.init(self, request.data, token=token`)